# Is there an API that can access Twitter analytics

Tags: twitter

I am planning to create a dashboard for a client regarding their twitter account's stats like daily tweets and retweets. I was able to access this (count only) but I am hoping to access these and backtrack stats from years ago. But twitter does not allow this.

Is there any other alternative on showing these stats with dates along with it? I was also hoping of accessing the Twitter analytics just like what I successfully did with my Google API dashboard. Although according here  https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2281 it is still impossible for Twitter.

I badly need this. Thank you guys in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Twitter does not provide an API for analytics data.

Sources, straight from Twitter itself:

- https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-analytics-api/27296
- https://twittercommunity.com/t/analytics-twitter-com-apis/25242

You might be able to do something with the "Export" (CSV) functionality present in the analytics dashboard, though.  Best of luck!

Comment: sorry to necrobump, but do you happen to know if this has changed since your answer?

Comment: No need to apologize, mostly because necrobump is an awesome new word I'm stealing as of this moment. :) Unfortunately, as far as I know, Twitter still doesn't allow access to this data :/ (I bet they would if you have lots of cash to burn...)

Comment: When I click on this links and connect, I got google alert that twittercommunity.com is spam and had malware ...

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a Twitter API for our group as well. There are two ways that you can go about getting access to an API for Twitter Analytics:

1. If you've got a big budget, you can go straight to the source. Twitter has a service called [GNIP](https://gnip.com/) that allows you access to pretty much data on all tweets since the beginning of Twitter. More specifically, GNIP has a [GNIP Insights API](https://www.gnip.com/insights/) that provides all the information that Twitter Analytics does.
2. Find a partner that has purchased access to GNIP ([Datasift](http://datasift.com/) for example). Usually these companies "resell" the data provided by GNIP, but restrict you to a set amount of topics or accounts that you want data for.

Comment: Looks like this is now available via the Twitter Enterprise APIs: https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/metrics